# Properties of differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $V\colon R^n\to R^n$ of class $C^1$ and with bounded prime order derivate. Prove that for all $x \in R^n$ the equation $y'(t)=V(y(t))$ with $y(0)=x$ has a unic solution of class $C^2$ defined in $R$.
Let $X(t,x)$ be a such solution.Prove that $X(s+t,x)=X(s,X(t,x))$.
Prove that $x\to X(t,x_0)$ is of class $C^1$ and 
$$\frac{d}{dt} \nabla_x X(t,x)=\nabla V(X(t,x))\nabla _x X(t,x)$$
(consider the equation satisfied by the incremental raports of X(t,x) in a fixed direction.)
Prove that the function $\nabla(t,x)=det\nabla_x X(t,x)$ satisfies the equation 
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\nabla(t,x)=div V(t,X(t,x))\nabla(t,x)$$

My thoughts: Since $V\in C^1$ with bounded differential we conclude that exists a unic solution and it's defined in $R$. Since $y'(t)$ is $C^1$ then $y(t)$ is $C^2$. $X(s+t,x)=X(s,X(t,x))$ is an obvious property of the transition map that follows from the unicity, isn't it?

Comment: $y'(t) = V(y(t))$ with $y(0)=x$ has a unique solution of class $\mathcal{C}^{2}$

and

$X(s+t,x)=X(s,X(t,x))$

both follow from Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem.

Comment: Can you help me prove the others? Thank you

Comment: To prove that $$\frac{d}{dt} \nabla_{x}X(t,x) = \nabla V(X(t,x)) \nabla_{x}X(t,x)$$, you may start from $\frac{d}{dt} \nabla_{x}X(t,x) = \nabla_{x} \frac{d}{dt}X(t,x)$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: For the last statement, you may use the fact that the differential of $\mathrm{det}$ is $\mathrm{D}_{M} \mathrm{det} \cdot H = \mathrm{tr}\left( {}^t \mathrm{Com}(M) H \right)$ where $\mathrm{Com}(M)$ is the comatrix of $M$. Tell me if you want a more detailed answer from a statement from your post.

Comment: how can I prove that the differential of det is what you say? Please give me a more detailed answer. Thank you

Comment: I posted a more detailed answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to prove that $\mathrm{D}_{M}\det \cdot H = \mathrm{tr}\left( {}^t \mathrm{Com}(M)H \right)$. It is a good exercise :

1. Compute $\mathrm{D}_{I}\det$ (the differential of $\det$ at $I$, the identity matrix) using the fact that $\det$ is a multilinear function on the columns of the matrix.
2. Compute $\mathrm{D}_{M}\det$ for $M \in \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.
3. Compute $\mathrm{D}_{M}\det$ for any matrix $M$ using the fact that $M \, \mapsto \, \det(M)$ is continuous and that $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $\nabla(t,x) = \det \left( \nabla_{x}X(t,x) \right)$. Let's differentiate this equality. Using the chain rule and the previous result on $\frac{d}{dt} \nabla_{x}X(t,x)$, we get :

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \nabla(t,x) = \mathrm{D}_{\nabla_{x}X(t,x)} \det \cdot \left( \frac{d}{dt} \nabla_{x}X(t,x) \right) $$

It gives :

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \nabla(t,x) = \mathrm{tr} \left( {}^t \mathrm{Com} \left( \nabla_{x}X(t,x)) \right) \nabla V(X(t,x)) \nabla_{x}X(t,x) \right) $$

Then, we use that $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$ for any couple of matrices. We have :

$$ \tag{$\star$} \frac{d}{dt} \nabla(t,x) = \mathrm{tr} \left( \nabla V \left( X(t,x) \right) \nabla_{x}X(t,x) {}^t \mathrm{Com} \left( \nabla_{x}X(t,x) \right) \right) $$

Here, we use that ${}^t \mathrm{Com}(M) M = M {}^t \mathrm{Com}(M) = \det(M)I$, which gives :

$$ \tag{$\star\star$} \nabla_{x} X(t,x) {}^t \mathrm{Com} \left( \nabla_{x} X(t,x) \right) = \det \left( \nabla_{x} X(t,x) \right)I $$

Using $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$, it follows that

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \nabla(t,x) = \det \left( \nabla_{x} X(t,x) \right) \mathrm{tr} \left( \nabla V(X(t,x)) \right) $$

because $\det\left( \nabla_{x}X(t,x) \right) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathrm{tr}$ is linear. To conclude, use that $\mathrm{tr} \left( \nabla V(X(t,x)) \right) = (\mathrm{div} V)(X(t,x))$. I hope this helps.